# React Native dev build on device expires?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am not sure if this is a thing, or possibly and issue. I am hoping others have experienced it. But every time I put a dev build on my iphone through xcode, the app works fine on the device while unplugged from the computer for about a week. Then the app crashes at the splash screen. Every dev build of an app I have loaded on my device has done this. Even example apps I have downloaded from the web.

Does a development build of the app expire, or maybe the certificates expire or some other issue that causes the app on the device to start crashing after its been on the device for a certain time?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could this be that the npm server is not running? I am looking for answer as well

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot put another build on your phone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution 1: Turn off the WiFi on your iPhone or just make sure your phone and your PC are not on the same WiFi Network.

Solution 2: Run your app on the device using a Static Js bundle. To build static bundle follow these [instructions for running on device via static bundle](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/240)

Reason: This happens because when your phone and PC are on the same WiFi network then the app on phone tries to connect to the app development server to load the latest Js bundle, but when it could not connect to development server or could not fetch the latest Js bundle then the app crashes. By turning off your WiFi or changing the Wifi network causes the application to load the pre-build bundle and prevents the app from crashing.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same thing and finally figured it out. If you're using a Xcode provisioning profile instead of signing up for the Apple Developer Program and paying yearly then what you're doing is getting a temporary profile that lasts about a week. Once it expires, any device with the app installed will stop working until you rebuild it with the new profile. You can see your profile/expiration if you go to General->Signing and click the 'i' next to provisioning profile.

Answer (score 2):

I hope If app is opening to splash screen then there is no wrong with application building. After Splash are you going to use any web services or related to your localhost site. If yes then definitely issue is there.
Let me know if it is helpful .

Answer (score 1):

When build on your phone, you want to change your scheme to `Release`. Please follow this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html, which will show you how to change your scheme to `Release`.

If you did lots of upgrade when developing, you might want to delete the `node_modules` folder, and do a clean `npm install` again, prior to build on phone process.